Quarto seems unable to handle very simple LaTeX modifier commands
This is silly, but I cannot seem to find a way out.
So, imagine you have a quarto document rendered to pdf. I just want some words to be of \Large{} size and others to be of \footnotesize{}.
So something like this:
---
title: "Proof of Concept"
author: "Your Name"
date: "2024-06-08"
format: pdf
---

The quick brown \Large{fox} jumps over the lazy \footnotesize{dog}.


Now, this renders correctly -- ie the compiler understands that some text must be large and other smaller, but keeps the { } around the text. Like this:

I tried several other solutions -- eg treating it as inline code, of the sort `{latex} \Large{text}', or verbatim, or putting { elsewhere... to no avail.
Of course I can make quarto keep the tex file and then go over it manually.
But it seems like a mightily stupid thing to do, the point of quarto being automatic document generation...

Unrelated to quarto, but such font commands are switches and don't take an argument. In latex, you should write {\Large fox} etc. If I remember correctly, you could use code fences with some special keyword to input raw latex in quarto.

ahah thanks! that might be it.
Problem is, going for {\Large fox} just prints the code.
I have now a workaround by switching back, like this
The quick brown \Large fox \normalsize jumps over the lazy \footnotesize dog \normalsize.
i.e. I "switch" back.
But maybe there is a better way

Such font commands are switches and don't take an argument. In real latex, you should write {\Large fox}.
You could use \begingroup\Large fox\endgroup as a workaround in quarto. Use {} as needed to prevent it from eating the space afterwards:
---
title: "Proof of Concept"
author: "Your Name"
date: "2024-06-08"
format: pdf
---

The quick brown \begingroup\Large fox\endgroup{} jumps over the lazy
\begingroup\footnotesize dog\endgroup.


